# How to migrate cases that make use of @content and @import with @content and @forward in SASS

Tags: sass, gulp-sass, dart-sass

I'm migrating a codebase from using `@import` to `@use` and `@forward`. Most of it is okay but I'm unsure what to do in a case where `@import` is used with `@content`.

Considering the following mixing that the only goal is to wrap styles in a class:

```css
@mixin alternative-styles {
  .parent-class {
    @content;
  }
}
```

The mixin is then used with `@import` to wrap all those styles in a `.parent-class`:

```css
@include alternative-styles {
  @import 'components';
}
```

I assumed replacing it with a `@forward` wouldn't work but have it a try anyway in this way:

```css
@include alternative-styles {
  @forward 'components';
}
```

This threw the following error:

```sh
Error: This at-rule is not allowed here.
   ╷
22 │   @forward 'components';
     │   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

I have found that the `sass-migration` tool solves the issue this way:

```css
@use 'sass:meta';
@use 'mixins';

@include mixins.alternative-styles {
  @include meta.load-css('components');
}
```

The `components.scss` files has multiple `@forward` statements to keep all component references in one place like this:

```css
// components.scss
@forward 'components/buttons';
@forward 'components/text';
```

After the sass compiler runs it results in an empty block:

```css
.parent-class {
}
```

Is there any way to achieve wrapping a bunch of styles in a class that supports the `@use` and `@forward` rules?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `meta.load-css` mixin actually does work after creating a separate prototype with the same structure:

```css
@use 'sass:meta';
@use 'mixins';

@include mixins.alternative-styles {
  @include meta.load-css('components');
}
```

More details on using `meta.load-css` for this case can be found in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/3095

The reason I got the empty `.parent-class` block was because I was making use of asynchronous compiling with the `gulp-sass` package. Replacing `sass().on(...)` with `sass.sync().on(...)` solved the issue.